# Oracle APEX - grabbing script output

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler, oracle-apex, utl-file

Does APEX make it possible to call a script using dbms_scheduler, utl_file or other
and grab it's output?

The goal is to pass a command to an external API and show a popup either if an exception is generated or a sucess message is received.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the script is a file on the database server's operating system, you should be able to invoke the script from APEX using either DBMS_SCHEDULER or via a [Java stored procedure](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241).  Personally, I'd tend to use the Java stored procedure approach just because that's what I've used in the past but it's solely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thanks Justin.
The Java procedure example seems a little dated (and I'm not used to it) but I'll try to put it together.